# Shiny / Shiny-Server does not render outputs (plots, datatable)

Tags: shiny, shiny-server

I'm having trouble with my shiny installation. I have Shiny Server (1.5.3.838) on Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS with Shiny package version 1.0.3. Here is the screenshot;
[image]

Shiny-server does not render the sample-app's plot. But i think the problem is not about the shiny-server because the same issue exists when i ran the application via Rstudio.

Things i've tried so far;

- Change the shiny-server log level to TRACE
- Change the application log level
- Install different versions of Shiny-server (1.5.x, 1.4.x)
- Install different versions of Shiny package (1.0.x)
- Try on different browsers (Chrome, Firefox, IE)
- Change the shiny-server conf file into this;

preserve_logs true;
sanitize_errors off;
disable_protocols xdr-streaming xhr-streaming iframe-eventsource iframe-htmlfile;

Edit: My R version is Microsoft R Server 9.1.0 (on top of MRO 3.3.3)

Comment: Have you found a solution to this? I've had the same experience on mro-3.4.3 and have read of others having this problem with other versions of Microsoft R.

Comment: @KevinArseneau nope, i had to migrate to R classic